TCC timer from ATSAME54 resets itself
I use an ATSAME54P20A. I want to use the timer TCC0 as a counter. An important function is that I can stop and start the counter again without it resetting itself. According to the data sheet, the Stop Command and the Re-Trigger Command seem to be suitable for this. For the Stop Command, see the data sheet in chapter 49.6.2.4 Counter Operation,

When a stop is detected while the counter is running, the counter will maintain its current value.

And for the re-trigger command it says,

If the re-trigger command is detected when the counter is stopped, the counter will resume counting operation from the value in COUNT.

So that's exactly what I want. However, my tests don't confirm that. After the following C++ code, 0 is in the register TCC0.COUNT, no matter what the value was before:
TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_STOP_Val;
while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB || !TCC0->STATUS.bit.STOP);

TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_RETRIGGER_Val;
while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB || TCC0->STATUS.bit.STOP);

TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_READSYNC_Val;
while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB);

So, contrary to the data sheet, the timer is reset. An exception is when you step through the lines of code in debug mode. Then there is no reset. For whatever reason. Can anyone tell me if I need to set a flag that I forgot to do or if it really is an mistake in the data sheet or something else entirely?
Here again a main.cpp that shows the case. If you go step by step between the two lines marked as breakpoints in debug mode, there is no reset, otherwise there is:
#include "sam.h"

int main(void)
{
    OSCCTRL->XOSCCTRL[1].reg = OSCCTRL_XOSCCTRL_ENABLE | OSCCTRL_XOSCCTRL_IPTAT(0x03) | OSCCTRL_XOSCCTRL_IMULT(0x04) | OSCCTRL_XOSCCTRL_CFDPRESC(0x3);
    
    OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLCTRLB.reg = OSCCTRL_DPLLCTRLB_REFCLK_XOSC1 | OSCCTRL_DPLLCTRLB_DIV(5);
    
    OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLRATIO.reg = OSCCTRL_DPLLRATIO_LDR(119) | OSCCTRL_DPLLRATIO_LDRFRAC(0);
    while (OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLSYNCBUSY.bit.DPLLRATIO);
    
    OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLCTRLA.reg = OSCCTRL_DPLLCTRLA_ENABLE;
    while (OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLSYNCBUSY.bit.ENABLE | OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLSTATUS.bit.LOCK || OSCCTRL->Dpll[0].DPLLSTATUS.bit.CLKRDY);
    
    GCLK->CTRLA.bit.SWRST = true;
    while (GCLK->SYNCBUSY.bit.SWRST);
    
    GCLK->GENCTRL[0].reg = GCLK_GENCTRL_SRC_DPLL0 | GCLK_GENCTRL_GENEN | GCLK_GENCTRL_DIV(1);
    while (GCLK->SYNCBUSY.bit.GENCTRL0);
    
    GCLK->PCHCTRL[TCC0_GCLK_ID].reg = GCLK_PCHCTRL_GEN_GCLK0 | GCLK_PCHCTRL_CHEN;
    while (!GCLK->PCHCTRL[TCC0_GCLK_ID].bit.CHEN);
    
    MCLK->APBBMASK.bit.TCC0_ = true;
    
    TCC0->CTRLA.bit.ENABLE = false;
    while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.ENABLE);
    
    TCC0->WAVE.bit.WAVEGEN = TCC_WAVE_WAVEGEN_MFRQ_Val;
    while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.WAVE);
    
    TCC0->CC[0].bit.CC = 0x7270e;
    while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CC0);
    
    TCC0->CTRLA.reg = TCC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV256 | TCC_CTRLA_ENABLE;
    while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.ENABLE);
    
    uint32_t Count = 0;
    
    while (Count < 0x20000)
    {
        TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_READSYNC_Val;
        while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB);
        
        Count = TCC0->COUNT.bit.COUNT;;
    }
    
    if (!TCC0->STATUS.bit.STOP)
    {
        TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_STOP_Val; //Breakpoint
        
        while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB || !TCC0->STATUS.bit.STOP);
    }
    
    if (TCC0->STATUS.bit.STOP) //Breakpoint
    {
        TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_RETRIGGER_Val;
        
        while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB || TCC0->STATUS.bit.STOP);
    }
    
    while (true)
    {
        TCC0->CTRLBSET.bit.CMD = TCC_CTRLBSET_CMD_READSYNC_Val;
        
        while (TCC0->SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB);
        
        Count = TCC0->COUNT.bit.COUNT;
    }
}

I found out that the error occurs when the timer is stopped. After that, the value of TCC0.COUNT is 0. If you write a value to TCC0.COUNT when the timer is stopped and then start it, this value is not reset.
I am working with Mircrochipstudio and the ARM GNU toolchain 6.3.1 used there. And this is the board I use:
SAM E54 CURIOSITY ULTRA DEVELOPMENT BOARD
